# Automatically determine MaxLength and use it for padding

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a model with a bunch of fields defined like this:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public DateTime R03DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? R03DateTo { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(80)]
    public string R03Place { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string R03Code { get; set; }
    // And so on....
}
```

At a certain point I need to export some of this data to fixed width files, and if a string has a MaxLength of x, then in the output file it should always be output right-padded with spaces up to x characters.

I'm hoping to re-use the fact that the string's MaxLength is always defined in the Model in order to flow this information through to the export.

At the moment, a typical export row function looks like this (ExDateTime is an extension method that formats the date in yyyyMMddhhmm format):

```
    private string GetR03Row()
    {
        return GetRowCode() + "03" +
               R03DateFrom.ExDateTime() +
               R03DateTo.ExDateTime() +
               (R03Place??"").PadRight(80) +
               (R03Code??"").PadRight(20);
    }
```

I'd like to replace the line

```
(R03Place??"").PadRight(80)
```

with something that uses the MaxLength attribute.

Every string will have a MaxLength.

UPDATE:

I've taken the suggestion below and turned it into an Extension Method:

```
    public static string PadToMax<T>(this string source, string propName)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var found = props.Where(m => m.Name.Equals(propName));

        if (!found.Any()) return source;

        var propertyInfo = found.First();
        var attrs = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false);

        if (!attrs.Any()) return source;

        foreach (var maxLengthAttribute in attrs.OfType<MaxLengthAttribute>())
        {
            return (source??"").PadRight(maxLengthAttribute.Length);
        }

        return source;
    }
```

which allows me to use this syntax to achieve what I want:

```
// (R03Place??"").PadRight(80) turns into
R03Place.PadToMax<Transaction>(nameof(R03Place))
```

This is fine. I'd love it if I could change the extension method to somehow work out the "Transaction" type and the name of the source string variable. But thi is close enough.

Comment: Where do you want to use such code? In a `ASP.NET MVC` view, controller? In a `WPF` Application, In a `BusinessLogic` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Olivier proposed should work.

Here another way:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var maxLength = GetMaxLengthAttributeValue<Transaction>("R03Place");
        Console.WriteLine("R03Place = {0}",maxLength);
        maxLength = GetMaxLengthAttributeValue<Transaction>("R03Code");
        Console.WriteLine("R03Place = {0}",maxLength);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static int? GetMaxLengthAttributeValue<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof (T).GetProperties();
        var found = props.Where(m => m.Name.Equals(propertyName));

        if (!found.Any()) return null;

        var propertyInfo = found.First();
        var attrs = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false);

        if (!attrs.Any()) return null;

        foreach (object attr in attrs)
        {
            MaxLengthAttribute maxLengthAttribute = attr as MaxLengthAttribute;
            if (maxLengthAttribute != null)
            {
                return maxLengthAttribute.Length;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Put the method in a helper class:

```
//You can use it as:    
(R03Place??"").PadRight(YourHelper.GetMaxLengthAttributeValue<Transaction>("R03Place").Value);

// with C# 6, you don't have to hard code the property name
  (R03Place??"").PadRight(YourHelper.GetMaxLengthAttributeValue<Transaction>(nameof(R03Place)).Value);
```

Comment: Considering the OP's comment on my answer, this is the way to go. I should have thought of it, since he tagged `reflection` in the question.

Comment: I'll take a look at this approach. Looks closer to what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Could you save the maxlength as a private field?

```
public class Transaction
{
    private int maxLengthPlace = 80

    public DateTime R03DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? R03DateTo { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(maxLengthPlace)]
    public string R03Place { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string R03Code { get; set; }
    // And so on....
}
```

and then use the same field later on?

```
(R03Place??"").PadRight(maxLengthPlace)
```

Comment: That's a lot of extra private fields. I don't think it will add any clarity. In my example there are only two strings, but in the actual project there are many classes, and dozens of strings, that I want to treat the same way. I'm trying to avoid writing the same number in two places, and while I appreciate your suggestion does this, I don't think I'd do it this way.